# how to set action to form in joomla modules

Tags: joomla

this is my file structure in my modules

```
tmpl
    default.php
helper.php
mod_helloword.php
mod_helloword.xml
```

i have this form in default.php file

```
<form action="" method="post"
enctype="multipart/form-data">
<label for="file">Filename:</label>
<input type="file" name="file" id="file"><br>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

i want to pass it after click on submit to heper.php file
in that form action attribute must set to what ??

Comment: Have you looked at this?
[joomla module development with form - how to process][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15059289/joomla-module-development-with-form-how-to-process?rq=1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need to set an action, you can simply give it a name. So you form would look something like this:

```
<form name="submit" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <label for="file">Filename:</label>
  <input type="file" name="file" id="file"><br>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Then your **helper.php** :

```
class ModHelloWorldHelper {
    public static function submit($file) {
        // some code goes here
    }
}
```

Then your **mod_helloworld.php** (which calls the function in the helper.php):

```
$input = new JInput;
$post = $input->getArray($_POST);

if ($post["submit"]) {
    modHelloWorldHelper::submit($file);
}
```

Please note that you will of course have to make a few changes to suits your needs as the code above is just there to give you a small head start